# Using ASIO to capture lots of UDP packets

Tags: c++, networking, udp, asio

I'm using the asio ( non boost version) library to capture incoming UDP packets via a 10GB Ethernet adapter.
150k packets a second is fine, but I start getting dropped packets when i got to higher rates like 300k packets/sec.

I'm pretty sure the bottleneck is in DMA'ing 300k seperate transfers from the network card to the host system.  The transfers aren't big only 1400 bytes per transfer, so not a bandwidth issue.

Ideally i would like a mechanism to coalesce the data from multiple packets into a single DMA transfer to the host. Currently I am using asio::receive, to do synchronous transfers which gives better performance than async_receive.

I have tried using the receive command with a larger buffer, or using an array of multiple buffers, but i always seem to get a single read of 1400 bytes.

Is there any way around this?

Ideally i would like to read some multiple of the 1400 bytes at a time, so long as it didn't take too long for the total to be filled.
ie. wait up to 4ms and then return 4 x 1400 bytes, or simply return after 4ms with however many bytes are available...

I do not control the entire network so i cannot force jumbo frames :(

Cheers,

Comment: Perhaps i should add that i am seeing 1 core of the machine sit at 100% usage, whilst running my test app.  I have lots of cores available, but it seems that receiving packets on a single port ends up being limited by a single thread....   Is this correct?

Comment: One thread can only use one core. But if you're CPU bound you need to examine your code, not network interfaces.

Comment: Gain maybe i should make my goal clearer,                       I am asking if there is any way to force the asio interface to deliver larger chunks of data, (at a slower rate)

Comment: So after more research it appears that RSS Queue setting is not working correctly in my test systems, does anyone know of a way enable proper RSS queue support in windows 10 Pro..  I set the property in the driver panel, but it does appear to working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you can try a workarround with tcpdump using the libcap library http://www.tcpdump.org/ and filtering to recive UDP packets

Comment: see above, i need cross platform support, so stuck with asio.   I am looking for a solution within the asio library, not a "use something else" solution.   I am very new to asio, and i suspect there may be things i am misusing..

Comment: Sorry i didn't do due diligince, on this. Apparently pcap is cross platform.  I am experimenting with it now and it looks like it might be a suitable interface for the task at hand...   Either way this was a useful suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I would remove the `asio` layer and go direct to the metal.

If you're on Linux you should use [*recvmmsg(2)*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmmsg.2.html) rather than `recvmsg()` or `recvfrom()`, as it at least allows for the possibility of transferring multiple messages at a time within the kernel, which the others don't.

If you can't do either of these things, you need to at least moderate your expectations. `recvfrom()` and `recvmsg()` and whatever lies over them in `asio` will never deliver more than one UDP datagram at a time. You need to:

- speed up your receiving loop as much as possible, eliminating all possible overhead, especially dynamic memory allocation and I/O to other sockets or files.
- ensure that the socket receiver buffer is as large as possible, at least a megabyte, via `setsockopt()/SO_RCVBUFSIZ`, and don't assume that what you set was what you got: get it back via `getsockopt()` to see if the platform has limited you in some way.

Comment: I have tried a winsock implementation of the same code and it performs in a similar manner to the asio Sync version.  Plus this is going to be used across multiple platforms, so i'm kinda stuck with asio.

Comment: Unfortunately, getting this level of performance pretty much requires platform-specific code.